# magento magmi categories creation of the fly

Tags: magento, csv, magento-1.7, magmi

I cannot create my products categories correctly on my magento store using magmi because my csv file is not compliant with magmi

my csv header is this:

```
Item Code,Price,Stock,Item Title,Category,Sub Category,Manufacturer,Part Number,Weight,Image,Warehouse,description one,description 2,EAN Number
SB-400-00,1.25,Sandberg Hard Back Case (Clear) for iPhone 4,Phones,Accessory,Sandberg,400-00,0.05,OR66300000242579.jpg,3,description one,Sandberg Hard Case for iPhone 4,5706595696
```

How I can play with Category,Sub Category to have the product in the correct subcat ?

- I try with value replace but I have no positive result.
- I try with On the fly category creator/importer no positive result too.

I have only the category without sub-cat.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a few Magmi plugins to format the data so that it can be processed correctly.

1. Make sure you have the **On the fly category creator/importer** enabled and the **Tree level separator:** configuration option set to `/` for the plugin.
2. Enable the **Column mapper** plugin and add `Category,Sub Category` to the **Mapped columns list**
3. For the **Category** field (in the **Column mapper** plugin), enter: `category`
4. For the **Sub Category** field (in the **Column mapper** plugin), enter: `subcategory`

   Your column mapper plugin configuration should look like this:

   [image: Magmi Column mapper]
5. Enable the **Value Replacer plugin** and enter `categories` into the **Replaced attributes** field.
6. For the **categories** field (in the **Value Replacer plugin**), enter: `{item.category}/{item.subcategory}`

   Your Value Replacer configuration should  look like this:

   [image: Magmi Value Replacer]
7. Click **Save Config** and run your import.